# Google places API data in linux(ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: shell, google-maps-api-3, wget

I want to get the data of a url and store it in a file. I used this command

```
wget -O output_file.txt "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true"
```

and it worked fine , and the data got stored in output_file.txt. Now when I used another url like this :

```
wget -O output_file.txt "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY"
```

, its showing an error

```
Resolving maps.googleapis.com (maps.googleapis.com)... 74.125.135.95, 2404:6800:4001:c01::5f 
Connecting to maps.googleapis.com (maps.googleapis.com)|74.125.135.95|:443... failed:
Connection refused. Connecting to maps.googleapis.com (maps.googleapis.com)|2404:6800:4001:c01::5f|:443... failed: Network is unreachable.
```

Also the data is not getting stored in the mentioned file. Also i tried with other url, it worked fine, except the google places api url just mentioned above. I would like to mention that the problematic url is working fine, if i just type it in some browser. But that way, i can only vbiew the data. But i want that data to be stored in some file.

all problems are in linux (ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: If the URL does work properly in a browser, try using `curl` and set the user-agent string (the `-A` option) to that of the working browser. That should work, unless the API's data is actually generated via JavaScript--which is a possibility but not very likely.

Comment: In the second URL you use https://, are you aware of that? So maybe the problem has something to do with that.